# Fineuploader to Azure Blob storage not always working

Tags: azure-blob-storage, fine-uploader

So I have implemented fineuploader uploading to azure blob storage and fully followed all instructions in the guides, including setting up CORS, error handling, signature creation, file completion notification etc. But for some reason Im getting inconsistent results from different people around the world.

I have tested successfully on Chrome 53 uploading large files. I have seen other users upload using Safari 9.1 on OS X 10.11 failing with errors that do not get logged to my server even though I have implemented an AJAX call when onError callback occurs.

Up until yesterday I had used fineuploader with AWS for the past 4 months with a success rate of around 80% of video files uploaded successfully. But I decided it was time to try Azure to see if I can get a higher success rate. Unfortunately so far I cant.

Would REALLY love any advice anyone has before I have to start looking at an alternative way for people to upload videos to our website....

Comment: According to your description, sometimes some users using Safari 9.1 on OS X 10.11 could not upload the file to Azure blob storage with Fine Uploader, but others could upload their files without the issue. From [this documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/browser-support.html), we could find Fine Uploader supports Safari 5+ (OS X). If most of users could upload the file to blob via your application, it could not be a CORS issue. You could let users report the error details that users could see in developer tool console tab(or network tab).

Comment: Yeah Im not really keen on asking paying customers to provide me with error details from their console tab.. :(

Comment: So at this point I have had to bite the bullet and switch to filestack instead and pay for it. I really wanted to use fineuploader, but without the option of paid support I just cant use it commercially.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, users’ networks could be unreliable, and uploads could fail. Fine Uploader offers the ability to retry via enable the retry option. You could check your code to make sure whether you enable the retry option.

```
retry: {
    enableAuto: true
}
```

Besides, it seems that **onError** callback function doesn’t help you collect the error logs, and you don’t want to let users report error details. You could try to setup same environment with Safari 9.1 on OS X 10.11 to reproduce the issue on your side. And Fine Uploader provides the **debug** option which will make the plugin spit out logging messages to the browser's developer tools console. You could enable the Debug mode to diagnose application errors, and then you could see errors in the console tab.

```
debug: true,
```

For more information about the retry option and the debug option, you could check [this documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/02-setting_options-azure.html).